# Tikz : node filling with text

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

Here is a minimal working example

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors %
%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{C2E15F}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}

%%%%%%%%%
% Fonts %
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=gray]{Helvetica Neue Light}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Graphic tools %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%
% Header %
%%%%%%%%%%
 \begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture,overlay]
   \node[](name)[align = left, inner sep = 0] {\fontsize{42pt}{0pt}\selectfont{My Name} \\
   \fontsize{20}{5pt}\selectfont{My function}};
   \draw (name.north west) -- +(20cm, 0);
   \draw (name.south west) -- +(20cm, 0);
   \node[](about)[align=left,inner sep=0, right=5.0cm of name.north east, anchor=north west]{%
   \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{mymail@mail.com} \\
   \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{+45 555 555} \\%
   \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{my adress} \\   
   \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{zipcode City} \\
   };
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

gives the following result

[image: latex1]

I would like the text in the rightmost node to "fill" the node i.e. to be perfectly aligned on the two lines I draw on the picture. Is it possible? Maybe using a minipage?
In the same idea, is it possible to force the text to fill the node horizontally so that the text is justified both right and left ?

EDIT: it seems the justified text can be obtained playing with the node options *text width*, *minimum width* and *justified text*. However, those options do not seem to work as soon as a "." characted is entered in the character screen as illustrated by the two following pictures.

[image: justifiedtext1]

[image: justifiedtext2]

The related codes adaptations are the following ones.

```
 \begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture,overlay]
   \node[](name)[align = left, inner sep = 0] {\fontsize{42pt}{0pt}\selectfont{My Name} \\
   \fontsize{20}{5pt}\selectfont{My function}};
   \draw (name.north west) -- +(20cm, 0);
   \draw (name.south west) -- +(20cm, 0);
   \node[](about)[draw=black, thin, align=left,inner sep=0, right=5.0cm of name.north east, anchor=north west, text width=4cm, minimum width=4cm, text justified]{%
   \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{mymail@mailcom} 
   \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{+45 555 555} 
   \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{my adress}   
   \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{zipcode City} 
   };
 \end{tikzpicture}


 \begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture,overlay]
   \node[](name)[align = left, inner sep = 0] {\fontsize{42pt}{0pt}\selectfont{My Name} \\
   \fontsize{20}{5pt}\selectfont{My function}};
   \draw (name.north west) -- +(20cm, 0);
   \draw (name.south west) -- +(20cm, 0);
   \node[](about)[draw=black, thin, align=left,inner sep=0, right=5.0cm of name.north east, anchor=north west, text width=4cm, minimum width=4cm, text justified]{%
   \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{mymail@mail.com} 
   \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{+45 555 555} 
   \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{my adress}   
   \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{zipcode City} 
   };
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: A minimal example should start with `\documentclass` and end width `\end{document}`.

Comment: you are right. I modified the code accordingly

Comment: Regarding your second point: do you want the email address etc pushed *right* over to the far right (but still left-aligned)?

Comment: No, what I want is (I think) called a justified text in Tikz. I can obtain it using the option text width, minimal width and text justified options for a node in tikz. Problem is, the code does not work as soon as a "." characted is entered. I edited my answer to show this possibility

Answer (score 6):

The vertical filling you can do when you measure height with the help of `\pgfgetlastxy`:

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\computeheight}[2]% name of node, name of targetmacro
{ \path (#1.south west);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\xsw}{\ysw}
  \path (#1.north east);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\xne}{\yne}
  %\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\nodewidth}{\xne-\xsw}% not needed here
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\nodeheight}{\yne-\ysw}
  %\xdef\widthofnode{\nodewidth}
  \expandafter\xdef\csname #2\endcsname{\nodeheight}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture,overlay]
  \node[right](name)[align = left, inner sep = 2pt] {\fontsize{42pt}{0pt}\selectfont{My Name} \\
  \fontsize{20}{5pt}\selectfont{My function}};

    % get height of node "name"
  \computeheight{name}{nameheight}

  \draw (name.north west) -- +(18cm, 0);
  \draw (name.south west) -- +(18cm, 0);

    % helper coordinate
    \coordinate[right=5.0cm of name.north east, anchor=north west] (about);
    % the data you want to use; the {} is for protecting commas in the entries,
    % so it's not neccessary here
    \foreach \t [count=\c] in {{mymail@mail.com},{+45 555 555},{my adress},{zipcode City}}
    {   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\topdistance}{(\c-1)*\nameheight/4+\nameheight/4*0.5}
        \node[below=\topdistance of about,align=left,anchor=west] (about\c) {\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{\t}};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is flat out MS Word type, terrible typesetting and I hope you have a valid reason for using this. Also I hope your address fills the line.

For text without a linebreak, TikZ has `align=justify` option. You can push things around with spaces instead of a line break.

```
 \begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture,overlay]
   \node[](name)[align = left, inner sep = 0] {\fontsize{42pt}{0pt}\selectfont{My Name} \\
   \fontsize{20}{5pt}\selectfont{My function}};
   \draw (name.north west) -- +(20cm, 0);
   \draw (name.south west) -- +(20cm, 0);
   \node[](about)[inner sep=0, right=5.0cm of name.north east, anchor=north west,align=justify, text width=3.5cm]{%
   \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{mymail@mail.com}
   \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{+45 555 555}\hspace{2em}
   \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{Wallie Street}\hspace{3em}
   \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{1234AB\hfill Lyon}
   };
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

*-I am calling for the follow-up on my job interview...*

*-Zero taste. Don't call us again.*

Comment: Your remark concerning typesetting is interesting. Do you have any website teaching the basics of typesetting? It could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

To get the "fill" effect you want, you could use this

```
\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{mymail@mail.com} \\[3pt]
\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{+45 555 555} \\[3pt]
\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{my adress} \\[3pt]   
\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{zipcode City}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The vertical filling can be achieved with a small computation inside a `\foreach` loop:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors %
%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{C2E15F}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}

%%%%%%%%%
% Fonts %
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=gray]{Arial}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Graphic tools %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%
% Header %
%%%%%%%%%%
 \begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture,overlay]
   \node[](name)[align = left, inner sep = 0] {\fontsize{42pt}{0pt}\selectfont{My Name} \\
   \fontsize{20}{5pt}\selectfont{My function}};
   \draw (name.north west) -- +(20cm, 0);
   \draw (name.south west) -- +(20cm, 0);
%    \node[](about)[align=left,inner sep=0, right=5.0cm of name.north east, anchor=north west]{%
%    \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{mymail@mail.com} \\
%    \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{+45 555 555} \\%
%    \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{my adress} \\   
%    \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont{zipcode City} \\
%    };
   \node(abouttop)[align=left,inner sep=0, right=5.0cm of name.north east, anchor=north west]{mymail@mail.com};
   \node(aboutbottom)[align=left,inner sep=0, right=5.0cm of name.south east, anchor=south west]{zipcode City};
   \newcommand{\nodelist}{{+45 555 555},{my adress}}
   \newcommand{\nodelistlength}{2} %try to calculate this automatically
   \foreach \nodetext [count=\nodenumber] in \nodelist
    {
    \node[align=left,inner sep=0,anchor=base west] at ($(abouttop.base west)!\nodenumber/(1+\nodelistlength)!(aboutbottom.base west)$){\nodetext};
    }
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'm not good at list computations in `LaTeX`, that's why it's a little bit hacked. This answer can be improved by:

1. Computing the length of the list of lines automatically.
2. Just submitting the 4 lines and stripping the first and last line off in order to place it explicitly automatically.
3. Use `tikz` styles.