# How to draw a nice and complex flowchart (combining table and flowchart)

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts, mindmaps

There are many ways to draw a simple flowchart, using packages like `tikz`. But recently I read a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.12454v4) and it seems that their complex flowchart is not a picture, but actually generated by latex. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

#### Edit

I really would like to know how to make a chart like this, so I made a concept of a simplified version:
[image]

According to the existing answers, I tried to draw a figure like the concept on my own with code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{row1/.style={
                        minimum width=90pt,
                        minimum height=10pt,
                        draw}}
        \tikzset{row2/.style={
                        minimum width=90pt,
                        minimum height=100pt,
                        draw}}
        \tikzset{row3/.style={
                        minimum width=90pt,
                        minimum height=30pt,
                        draw}}
        \tikzset{round/.style={circle, 
                        draw=black!60, 
                        fill=orange!5, 
                        thick}}
        \tikzset{square/.style={rectangle, 
                        draw=black!60, 
                        fill=blue!5, 
                        thick}}
        \tikzset{arrow/.style={rectangle, 
                        draw=red!60, 
                        fill=red!5, 
                        thick}}
        \node[row1] (C1_1) {COL1};
        \node[row1, anchor=west] at (C1_1.east) (C2_1) {COL2};
        \node[row1, anchor=west] at (C2_1.east) (C3_1) {COL3};
        \node[row2, anchor=south, below=0] at (C1_1.south) (C1_2) {Some other text};
        \node[row2, anchor=south, below=0] at (C2_1.south) (C2_2) {Some other text};
        \node[row2, anchor=south, below=0] at (C3_1.south) (C3_2) {Some other text};
        \node[row3, anchor=south, below=0] at (C1_2.south) (C1_3) {Some other text};
        \node[row3, anchor=south, below=0] at (C2_2.south) (C2_3) {Some other text};
        \node[row3, anchor=south, below=0] at (C3_2.south) (C3_3) {Some other text};

        \node[square, below = -30] at (C1_2) (SA) {A};
        \node[square, below = -30] at (C2_2) (SB) {B};
        \node[square, below = -30] at (C3_2) (SC) {C};
        \node[square, below = 10] at (C3_2) (SD) {D};
        \node[round, below = 10] at (C2_2) (RO) {O};

        \draw[->] (SA) -- (SB);
        \draw[->] (SB) -- (SC);
        \draw[->] (SA) -- (RO);
        \draw[->] (SB) -- (RO);
        \draw[->] (RO) -- (SD);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Below is how my best-I-can-do figure looks like:

[image]

It seems that it still needs a lot of manual adjustments and improvements.

I would like to know how can we write a better latex implementation to draw something similar to my concept or to the original figure I posted. For "better" I mean the ways to make my implementation prettier or maybe the methods to save those manual adjustments needed.

Comment: For our reviewers: I don't think this one should be closed. It can be done by Tikz, yes, but requires some level of practice and experience, a novice usually can't have. With a novice to Tikz I'd be a bit more forgiving with this question. // See my answer to understand the requirements w.r.t. Tikz ...

Comment: @MS-SPO, for sure can be done by use of `tikz-pgf` ... but OP question is sort of `do-this-for-me`. So far he not show any of own effort to draw this.  Maybe the best solution for him is insert this image by `\includegraphics`.

Comment: I should ask more specific questions. My intention was not "do-this-for-me", I showed no effort because I have no idea where to start: drawing boxes and arrows using Tikz is all I know. I've updated my question.

Comment: A box can be drawn using either a `\node` (maybe in combination with the `fit` library) or, after having typeset `\node`s, using a `rectangle` that goes from `(A.north east)` to `(B.south west)` for example. At least this would be a way to completely draw this using Ti*k*Z what is probably the most straight-forward way.

Comment: Dear @TianjianQin , when you see something like this you should keep in mind the complexity is proportional to the effort put in even if you are an expert in either tikz or even more WYSIWYG programs like inkscape, and everything can be integrated without losing the quality of the vectors If you want a similar example you ask for too much effort and it is not a place for that, unless you have something ready to show. Also if you search a little more you will find extremely complicated examples.

Comment: @TianjianQin, I'd advise editing our question, adding some simple diagram you did yourself. This is a complex diagram to draw, and learning how to break the problem into small pieces and how to make them work together is an important skill to develop. [This question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/642435/140133) might help with the tikzset command to define the main concepts of your draw. [This answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/646268/140133) shall help you to learn how to define nodes with figures.

Comment: *Suggestion*: Post a specific question about how to draw chemicals like the image. I had some ideas for a workaround, but there might be people who knows better about chemicals than me.

Comment: @FHZ Thanks for the suggestion, I will go back and post my own example following your answer. I was actually not looking for how to draw chemicals, I was interested in how these elements were arrranged together on one plot

Comment: @JLeonV. I've improved my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just because of the challenging and unhealthy fun, around 160 lines of code maybe 4 hours, although the sun has already risen, anyway I hope it serves to encourage those who are starting out that everything can be done but it takes time and effort and etc. Write down some of the quick reference pages for code that I don't even remember. When analyzing the file you linked, I tried to decompose it into vectors but it has the peculiarity that it cannot be decomposed in the vector editor, I don't know the reason but since it exists it can be done, something to find out somewhere.

RESULT:

[image]

NMWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xstring} % To put some dummy.
\usepackage{amsmath} % for equations
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds,ducks,calc,arrows.meta,fit}

%CUSTOMIZED PALLETE OF COLORS USING A COLOR PICKER TOOL FOR THIRD PARTIES
\definecolor{GREEN}{HTML}{385723}
\definecolor{BLUE}{HTML}{2E5496}
\definecolor{BLUEB}{HTML}{5B9BD5}
\definecolor{BLUEC}{HTML}{4C7DAA}
\definecolor{ORANGE}{HTML}{F8CBAD}
\definecolor{GREY}{HTML}{D8D8D8}
% ALL THE POSTS OBTAINED BY ASKING FOR SOME CONTRETE QUESTION ON THE WEB.
%Tikz /.style with two parameters -> https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21395/154390
%Tikz : node filling with text -> https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117444/154390
% How can I get bold math symbols? -> https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/154390
% Is it possible to generate a set amount of words using lipsum? -> https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462453/154390
% Bold, italics and underlining -> https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bold%2C_italics_and_underlining

\newcommand{\mystring}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
    vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
    mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
    Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
    et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
    metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
    eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
    quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
    faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. 
    Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
    eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
    rutrum.}
% Using \StrBefore[20]{\mystring}{ } its posible to put some number of words by this command.

\def\DUCK{% TO PUT DUCKS IN NODES
    \begin{tikz}
        \tikz\shuffleducks\duck[\randomhead,scale=0.3];
        \tikz\shuffleducks\duck[\randomhead,scale=0.3,xshift=1cm];
        \tikz\shuffleducks\duck[\randomhead,scale=0.3,xshift=-1cm];
    \end{tikz}
}
\def\MUX#1#2{% to no repeat the code of operators
        \node[circle,draw,inner sep=-0.5pt,minimum height =.5cm,line width=1.5pt,#1] (#2) {};
        \draw[line width=1.5pt] (#2.0)--(#2.180)(#2.90)--(#2.-90);
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%Environment options
        BoxH/.store in=\BoxH,BoxH=10mm, % To avoid writin minimum height or width
        BoxW/.store in=\BoxW,BoxW=10mm,
        Arrow/.style 2 args= {draw=#1,-{Triangle[angle=120:.5cm 0.3,scale length=0.5*#2,scale width=0.3*#2]},line width=#2*1.2mm},
        H/.style 2 args= {draw=#1,rectangle,fill=#1,text=white,font=\sf\footnotesize,text width=#2, align=center},% H: For headers
        B/.style = {rectangle,text=black,font=\sf\tiny,text width=#1}, % B: for bodies
        L/.style = {draw=BLUEC,rectangle,text=white,font=\sf\scriptsize,text width=#1,fill=BLUEB,align=center,rounded corners=2pt}, % L: for learneable modules
        F/.style = {draw=#1,rectangle,fill=#1,minimum height=\BoxH, minimum width=\BoxW, inner sep=0}, % F: for features, all of these are nmonics to write fast and make code shorter.
    ]
    % Start drawing the thing.
    % Heads
    \node[H={BLUE}{3.7cm}](H1){Positional encodings (PE)};
    \node[H={BLUE}{3.7cm},right=1mm of H1](H2) {Structural encodings (SE)};
    \node[H={BLUE}{2.7cm},right=1mm of H2](H3) {Graph features};
    \node[H={GREEN}{4.5cm},right=1mm of H3](H4) {GPS layers};   
    %Bodies
    \node[B=3.9cm,below=1mm of H1, align=justify](PE-1){
        {\bfseries Local PE} \StrBefore[20]{\mystring}{ }\\ %inside a node when align is defined use \\ to jump to other line.
        \[
        \lim_{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
        \]
        {\bfseries Relative PE} \StrBefore[20]{\mystring}{ }
    };
    
    \node[B=3.9cm,below=9.5cm of H1,align=justify](PE-2){
        {\bfseries DeepSet} \StrBefore[20]{\mystring}{ }\\
        \\
        {\bfseries SignNet} \StrBefore[20]{\mystring}{ }
    };
    %Second column
    \node[B=3.9cm,below=1mm of H2,align=justify](SE-1){
        {\bfseries Local PE} \StrBefore[20]{\mystring}{ }\\
        \[
        R^*=\sum_{i=1}^n|RX_i-Y_i\|^2_2,
        \]
        {\bfseries Batch-norm} \StrBefore[20]{\mystring}{ }
    };
    
    \node[B=3.9cm,below=9.5cm of H2, align=justify](SE-2){
        {\bfseries DeepSet} \StrBefore[20]{\mystring}{ }\\
        \\
        {\bfseries MLP} \StrBefore[20]{\mystring}{ }
    };
    %third column
    \node[B=2.9cm,below=1mm of H3, align=justify](GF-1){
        {\bfseries Nodes features} \StrBefore[10]{\mystring}{ }\\
        \\
        {\bfseries Global features} \StrBefore[10]{\mystring}{ }\\
        \\
        {\bfseries Edge features} \StrBefore[10]{\mystring}{ }
    };
        
    \node[B=2.9cm,below=9.5cm of H3, align=justify](GF-2){
        {\bfseries MPL} \StrBefore[15]{\mystring}{ }
    };
    %fourth column
    \node[B=4.7cm,below=1mm of H4, align=justify](GF-1){
        {\bfseries MPNN layer} \StrBefore[11]{\mystring}{ }\\
        {\bfseries Transformer layer} \StrBefore[15]{\mystring}{ }\\
        {\bfseries Residual connections} \StrBefore[10]{\mystring}{ }\\
        {\bfseries MLP} Some text \underline{underline}.\\
    };
    %Drawing Another nodes
    \node[L=1cm,below=3mm of PE-1](MLP){MLP};
    \node[F=ORANGE,BoxW=3.5cm, BoxH=8mm, below=3mm of MLP](MLP-1){\DUCK};
    \node[F=GREY,BoxW=3.5cm, BoxH=8mm, below=1mm of MLP-1](MLP-2){\DUCK};
    \node[F=GREY,BoxW=3.5cm, BoxH=8mm, below=1mm of MLP-2](MLP-3){\DUCK};
    \node[F=GREY!50!ORANGE,BoxW=2cm, BoxH=8mm, right=1mm of MLP-1](MLP-4){\DUCK};
    \node[L=1cm,right=5mm of MLP-4](MLP2){MLP};
    \node[L=1.3cm,below left=5mm and -18mm of MLP-3](BN){batch-norm};
    \node[L=1.3cm,below=3mm of BN](MLP3){MLP};
    \node[L=1.2cm,right=3mm of MLP3](SN){sign-net};
    \node[L=1.2cm,above=0.5mm of SN](DS){deep-set};
    \node[B=1.5cm,above=0.1mm of DS,align=center,inner sep=0](Text){any variable input size network};
    \MUX{below=3mm of SN}{op-1};
    \MUX{on grid,below=-2.5mm of op-1-|MLP2}{op-2};
    \MUX{on grid,right=3cm of op-2}{op-3};
    \MUX{on grid,right=2cm of op-3}{op-4};
    
    
    %drawing some Arrows
    
    \draw[Arrow={GREY}{1}](MLP-2.180) -- ++(-2mm,0) coordinate (temp) |- (BN.180);
    \draw[Arrow={GREY}{1}](BN) -- (MLP3);
    \draw[Arrow={GREY!50!ORANGE}{1}](MLP-4)--(MLP2);
    \draw[Arrow={GREY}{1}](MLP3) |- (op-1);
    \draw[Arrow={GREY}{1}](SN) -- (op-1);
    \draw[Arrow={GREY}{1.2}](op-1) -- (op-2);
    \draw[Arrow={GREY}{1.3}](op-2) -- (op-3);
    \draw[Arrow={GREY}{1.4}](op-3) -- (op-4);
    \draw[Arrow={GREY}{1}](MLP2)--(op-2);
    \draw[Arrow={ORANGE}{1}](MLP-1)--(MLP);
    \draw[Arrow={ORANGE}{1}](MLP)-|(op-4);
    
    %finishing
    \node[F=GREY!50!GREEN,BoxW=2.5cm, BoxH=4cm, right=10mm of op-4, align=center](END){\DUCK \\ \DUCK \\ \DUCK \\ \DUCK };
    \draw[Arrow={ORANGE}{1}](MLP)-|(op-4);
    \draw[Arrow={GREY!50!GREEN}{2}](op-4)--(END);
    %some use of fit
    
    \node[draw,BLUEB,line width=1pt,rounded corners,dashed,fit=(SN)(DS)(Text)]{};
    
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]% For the shadows boxes in background.
        \fill[GREY!15] (H1.south east)++(0,-1mm) rectangle (H1.south west|- PE-2.-90);
        \fill[GREY!15] (H2.south east)++(0,-1mm) rectangle (H2.south west|- PE-2.-90);
        \fill[GREY!15] (H3.south east)++(0,-1mm) rectangle (H3.south west|- PE-2.-90);
        \fill[GREEN!5] (H4.south east)++(0,-1mm) rectangle (H4.south west|- PE-2.-90);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

---

**EXTRA**
If some manuals seem like a lot of text to you, try [visual tikz](http://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf), you have code and result, it helped me a lot.

Comment: It is an awesome implementation, I could use your code as a template. Thank you for the manual, I find it very useful.

Comment: Which package are the arrows from? I am trying to draw the arrow in my own document, I added `\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds,ducks,calc,arrows.meta,fit}` but got an error saying Arrow command unknown, with `\draw[Arrow={GREY}{1}]`

Comment: Found it, it is a customized arrow defined by `Arrow/.style 2 args= {draw=#1,-{Triangle[angle=120:.5cm 0.3,scale length=0.5*#2,scale width=0.3*#2]},line width=#2*1.2mm}`

Comment: And yes, also the majority of learning is understanding the crazy code that you develop once you master something, it's good that you will find the lines you need, in the nodes there are reserved words if you find one that is not it is probably a style and it is defined above .

Comment: Nice use of `tikzducks`.

Answer (score 3):

**How to** make it, in generalized terms, which may need some finer details here and there (like opacity etc.), see the [pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/):

#### 1. Separating the usual from the unusual

If you remove in your mind all those `color`s, `rounded corner`s, `arrow tip`s etc. the vast majority of components are ordinary nodes and lines, using some more colorful `styles`.

What is remaining then are some structures which need a little more considerations:

- the circle with a plus-sign
- the 4 vertical color-scales (min .. max etc.)
- some layered structures (green, right)
- some labels (x L etc.)
- legend (lower right)
- chem-like figures
- the 4 columns with a kind of "I'm in the background" effect

#### 2. Possible approaches for the unusual parts

There are often more alternatives than I'm listing here. This is just to line out, how it could be achieved.

##### 2.1 Circle+Plus

- could be a `shape`, i.e. a `\node`, with some "+" text
- could be a `\pic`, which just draws a circle and two axes

So `\pic` seems to be a structure to be used often. Think of it as a kind of macro in Tikz-terms.

##### 2.2 Colorful scales

There's a fading-library, see the pgfmanual. Placing 0, min, max is just a `\node` away, and you probably will introduce 3-4 `\pic`s or just one or two using `arg`uments.

##### 2.3 Layered structure

There's a whole chapter in the pfgmanual about how to do this.

##### 2.4 Placing lables ...

... as `\node` will always work.

##### 2.5 Legend

Could be done separately, is perhaps better addressed with the columns.

##### 2.6 Chem-like figures

Basically these are simple objects (circles) which could be created by a few `\foreach` loops, which could include individual colors (see pgfmanal).

A lazy solution would create half a dozen similar `\pic`s, with varying colors and labels inside. Sophisticared solutions may address it all in one go: @Qrrbrbirlbel will certainly have a few tricks to show here.

The ones with the orange background look very much the same, while just the contrasts seem to create a different visual perception. The smeared out ones may be approximated by some wider line width, or matched exactly by the mindmap-library. It's a matter of balancing effect vs. effort.

##### 2.7 Column-structure

There are several options, too, like:

1. Perceive it all as one big Tikz-drawing. I.e. place `\node`s for the headers, other `\node`s for the text (which could and should be Latex: `\node at (0,-2) {Local PE as node ...};`). Probably you'd want to put those columns inside a layer, see above.
2. WHEN you can provide transparency for the Tikz-drawing in the middle, you just overlay the drawing with whatever table- or minipage-structure seems appropriate. (I never tried this, but speculate, it could be done.)

Comment: Thank you for the instruction. I've updated my question

Comment: Very good. However, when you can add some code of your trial to your question, this can be helpful.

Comment: I've added a concept and my own code

Comment: @TianjianQin, great! Should this question be closed (there's some dynamics in this process), I'd encourage you to post it again, perhaps in a bit modified form. Keep on, you are on a good track.

Answer (score 3):

## Introduction

This answer provided a quick start to the kind of result you want, presenting some methods to organize your styles.

To organize our solution, let's divide it in 3 files:

1. The main mew file: `mwe.tex`;
2. The style file: `myTikzsetStyle.sty`;
3. The TikZ draw file: `input_mwe_tikz.tex`.

Please, save all of them in the same folder and compile the `mwe.tex`.

### mwe.tex

The main file is simple, it calls the package `tikz` and its libraries; our own style file, and the `chemfig` package.

You may find more suitable packages for your chemicals, or draw them in another software and insert them as figures.

To make the insertion of the chemical figure more compact and easy to change in the future, I defined a command named `\chemA`. We just need to change its definition to change the result. This is the base concept, we will return to in the style file.

#### mwe.tex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\usepackage{myTikzsetStyle}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\newcommand{\chemA}{
  \chemfig{[:75]R-C(=[::+60]O)-[::-60]O-[::-60]C(=[::+60]O)-[::-60]R}
}

\begin{document}
  \input{input_mwe_tikz}
\end{document}
```

### myTikzsetStyle.sty

Style files are not only useful for organizing your code or text, but also for being reusable.

The last instruction of each `tikzset` defines the `/.default` style. The idea is always to define the `/.default` to be able to use the style without adding parameters all the time.

The tikzsets are:

- `addCross`: adds an `X` on the figure you define for the node;
- `addSum`: same as `addCross` with a `+`;
- `myBlock`: defines the standard block, many variations are possible;
- `mySimpleArrow`: defines the standard arrow;
- `myVecArrow`: defines an arrow with different color at the edge and at the middle;
- `myInnerColor`: useful for keeping internal color of `myVecArrow` consistent under connections;
- `myVecArrowColor`: special case from `myVecArrow` to be used in special connections;
- `myInnerNonWhite`: used together with `myVecArrowColor` for connections;
- `figNode`: defines a way to insert external figures.

To insert the texts above, I chose to use `newcommand` as an alternative method to create one command for adding the texts:

- `\myTextTable`: the first parameter is not mandatory and it is the parameters for the `scope` block.
- Help about [break lines in a node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123671/140133).
- Help about [vertical alignment in a node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430001/140133).

#### myTikzsetStyle.sty file

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{myTikzStyle}[2023-12-03 Custom Package to draw my own styles with TikZ]

\tikzset{addCross/.style n args={6}{
    minimum size={#5 mm}, %minimum height=10mm,
    path picture={
      \draw[#6]
      (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west)
      (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east);
      \node at ($(path picture bounding box.south)!0.4!(path picture bounding box.center)$) {#1};
      \node at ($(path picture bounding box.west)!0.4!(path picture bounding box.center)$)  {#2};
      \node at ($(path picture bounding box.north)!0.4!(path picture bounding box.center)$) {#3};
      \node at ($(path picture bounding box.east)!0.4!(path picture bounding box.center)$)  {#4};
    }
  },
  addCross/.default={}{}{}{}{10}{}
}
\tikzset{addSum/.style n args={6}{
    minimum size={#5 mm}, %minimum height=10mm,
    path picture={
      \draw[#6]
      (path picture bounding box.south) -- (path picture bounding box.north)
      (path picture bounding box.west) -- (path picture bounding box.east);
      \node at ($(path picture bounding box.south west)!0.6!(path picture bounding box.center)$) {#1};
      \node at ($(path picture bounding box.south east)!0.6!(path picture bounding box.center)$)  {#2};
      \node at ($(path picture bounding box.north west)!0.6!(path picture bounding box.center)$) {#3};
      \node at ($(path picture bounding box.north east)!0.6!(path picture bounding box.center)$)  {#4};
    }
  },
  addSum/.default={}{}{}{}{10}{black}
}
\tikzset{myBlock/.style n args={2}{
    every node/.style={rectangle,draw, text=black,
      minimum width=#1, minimum height=#2,}
  },
  myBlock/.default={1cm}{1cm}
}
\tikzset{mySimpleArrow/.style n args={2}{
    >={latex[#1]},
    every path/.style={draw=#2}
  },
  mySimpleArrow/.default={black}{black}
}
\tikzset{myVecArrow/.style n args={4}{
    thick, #1, decoration={markings, mark=at position
      1 with {\arrow[semithick, #2]{triangle 60[fill=#3]}}}, % open triangle
    double distance=1.4pt, shorten >= 5.5pt,
    preaction = {decorate},
    postaction = {draw,line width=1.4pt, #4, shorten >= 4.5pt}
  },
  myVecArrow/.default={black}{black}{white}{white}
}
\tikzset{myInnerColor/.style={
    semithick, #1, line width=1.4pt, shorten >= 4.5pt
  },
  myInnerColor/.default={white}
}
\tikzset{myVecArrowColor/.style={
    myVecArrow={red}{blue}{orange}{green}}
}
\tikzset{myInnerNonWhite/.style={
    myInnerColor={cyan}}
}
\tikzset{figNode/.style={
    path picture={
      \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {#1};}}
}

\newcommand{\myTextTable}[5][]{
  \begin{scope}[#1]
    \node[rectangle, fill=#2, text=#3, text centered, minimum width=80, minimum height=10] at (0,0.5) {
      \begin{tabular}{c}
        \textbf{#4}
      \end{tabular}
    };
    \node[minimum width=20, minimum height=10, align=left, text width = 0.25\textwidth, anchor=north] at (0,0) {
        {#5}
    };
  \end{scope} 
}
```

### input_mwe_tikz.tex

The key idea is always to define the *largest set of common features possible*, it means, use the environment scope with parameters.

At the first block, there are some red dashed rectangles, one of the filled with green.

The second block are the circle nodes applying purple. Here I added the `addCross` and `addSum` from the own style. Notice where it became purple and where it didn't.

The third block is the set of nodes using the style `myBlock`. This is normally the first block to draw and to define the position of its elements. Here I inserted two nodes using `figNode` and another node with the chemical.

The fourth block contains the basic set of `mySimpleArrow`, followed by the fifth block in the `foreach` loop to insert the `myVecArrow`, this is a special arrow with a colored space in the middle.

In the sequence there is a `myVecArrow` with parameters followed by a `foreach` with `myVecArrowColor` and `myInnerNonWhite`. Notice how the arrows combine nicely at the bifurcation. Just ignore the unusual color scheme.

Finally, the last block are the text above using `\myTextTable`. As we would use the same style more than once, we defined a command able to change some features without repeating the whole code over and over. If any change is necessary, we just do them at the command definition.

#### input_mwe_tikz.tex file

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
  \begin{scope}[dashed, red]
    \draw (-3,-2.25) rectangle ++(5,3.25);
    \draw[fill opacity=0.4,fill=green!50] (-4.5,2.25) rectangle ++(8,3.5);
  \end{scope}
  
  \begin{scope}[purple]
    \node[circle,draw,addCross={$+$}{$+$}{}{}{10}{black}] (N1) at (-2,0) {};
    \node[addSum] (N2) at (5,0) {};
    \node[circle,draw,addSum={1}{2}{3}{4}{10}{blue}] (N3) at (5,-2) {};
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[myBlock]
    \node (A) at (0,-1.5) {A};
    \node (B) at (-4,0) {B};
    \node[figNode={\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-c}}] (C) at (3,0) {};
    
    \node[figNode={\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck}}] (D) at (-3,4) {};
    \node (chemA) at (0.5,4) {\chemA};
    
    \node (I) at (0,0) {$\displaystyle \int$};
  \end{scope}
  
  \begin{scope}[mySimpleArrow]
    \path[->] ($(B)+(-1.5,0)$) node[above]{$u$} -- (B);
    \path[->] (B) -- (N1);
    \path[->] (N1) -- (I) node[midway, above] {$\dot{x}$};
    
    \path[->] (I) -- ++(1.5,0) coordinate(x) node[above]{$x$} -- (C);
    \path[->] (x) |- (A) -| (N1);
    
    \path[->] (C) |- (N3) node[below,midway]{$\hat{z}$};
    \path[->] (N3) -- ++(1.5,0) node[above]{$z$};
  \end{scope}
  
  \foreach \f in {myVecArrow}{
    \draw[\f] (B) |- (D);
    \draw[\f] (C) -- (N2) node[above,midway]{$\hat{y}$};
    \draw[\f] (N2) -- ++(1.5,0) node[above]{$y$};
  };
  
  \draw[myVecArrow={cyan}{red}{violet}{violet}] (D) -- (chemA);
  
  \foreach \f in {myVecArrowColor,myInnerNonWhite}{
    \draw[\f] (chemA) -| (C);
    \draw[\f] (chemA) -| (N2);
  };
  
  \begin{scope}[shift={(-3,8)}]
    \myTextTable{blue}{white}{\Large{Title A}}{Text 1.}
    \myTextTable[shift={(3,0)}]{blue}{white}{\Large{Title B}}{Text 2.}
    \myTextTable[shift={(6,0)}]{green!50!black}{white}{\Large{Title C}}{This is a very long text, yet not so long.}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

## Result

The following image show our results.

[image]

Comment: This is an amazing example. BTW I somehow ignored that there are chemicals in the image I've provided, because I was focusing on the aspect of the layout.

Comment: My guess: if we want to make the three columns like table columns, we just need to add three grey and transparent background rectangles ?

Comment: I've added a concept and my own implementaion, I hope this made my question clearer